# Fingerprint reader fails in 9 out of 10 times

Tags: authentication, fingerprint-reader

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04. The procedure for recording fingerprints works alright. Pam authentification works too.

According to `lsusb` I get

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0c28 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
```

But out of 10 tries it fails 9 times. Since it's a dual-boot machine I tried it on Windows 10, where it works 9 times out of 10 tries, so I assume it is not a hardware issue. Any news about this?

Thank you for your help